# Find Next Function

Tags: vb.net

I have a small problem for which I need help.

I have a webbrowser, and a button that finds a text from a class, well heres the code below:

```
Dim word As String = (WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("P").Cast(Of HtmlElement) _
       .FirstOrDefault(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("className") = "tagline").InnerText)

    Dim lastWord As String = word.Split(" ").Last

    If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(lastWord) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(lastWord)
    End If
```

The site has multible classes with the name "tagline", and I want the button to get the next one after I press it.
How can I do this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a global variable that keeps the index of the "tagline" that you want to retrieve. And use this indexer as a parameter for the Skip method to apply to the sequence returned by a Where instead of FirstOrDefault

```
' Declared at the global level
Dim index as Integer = 0

' At each button press you write
 Dim word As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("P") _ 
   .Cast(Of HtmlElement) _
   .Where(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("className")  = "tagline") _
   .Skip(index) _ 
   .First().InnerText
Dim lastWord As String = word.Split(" ").Last
index = index + 1
```

So at the next button press you skip to the second element then to third and so on. However this poses a problem. You should know how many elements are present in your WebBrowser Document to avoid requesting an inexistant element. So perhaps it is better to get all the elements with the "tagline" attribute and keep them in a list where they can be easily retrieved

```
' Declared at the global level
Dim index as Integer = 0
Dim elements = new List(Of HtmlElement)()

' After you have loaded the document
elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("P") _ 
           .Cast(Of HtmlElement) _
           .Where(Function(el) _ 
              el.GetAttribute("className")  = "tagline") _
           .ToList()
```

and in the button code just

```
if index < elements.Count Then
    Dim word = elements.Skip(index).First().InnerText
    Dim lastWord As String = word.Split(" ").Last
    index = index + 1
End if
```

Comment: Newbie here. How can I make it to load all the elements to a listbox..?
Also the site has 25 elements.

Comment: Just set the DataSource of the listbox to the elements retrieved or to the strings that you want to show. But this is enough material for another question (that I suggest you to post)

Comment: Thanks mate! Everything is now working like I wanted to. Thanks for the help! :)